# Find $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(xy+x+y)=f(xy)+f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function that satisfies
$$
f(xy+x+y)=f(xy)+f(x)+f(y)
$$
Find $f$ and prove that
$$
f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)
$$

Comment: The identity function obviously satisfies that equation. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, and obviously all functions of the form $f(x)=ax$ satisfy it, but it must be proved that no other function does.

Comment: Is $R$ the real numbers here or an arbitrary ring?

Comment: Finding $f$ will not be possible in general. Viewing the real numbers as a vector space over the rationals, any linear map $f$ will satisfy your relation. Now by the axiom of choice there is an uncountable basis for the reals over the rationals, and you can prescribe $f$ arbitrarily on this basis. (If you assume that $f$ is continuous, or just locally bounded or something, this can not happen, though...)

Comment: For such exercices, you can start to find relations for integers, rationals by playing on $x$ and $y$ values (easily, $f(0)=0$, $f(-x) = f(x)$). But you will have problem at the end without other assumptions on $f$. This is [Cauchy functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation), with clear cut solutions on rationals. It gets weirder on $\mathbb{R}$, as you can see from the first lines of the above link. You will need boundedness, continuity, monotonicity or other constraints.

Comment: Badly posed question. You can't "find $f$". See the references provided by @LaurentDuval

Comment: @Elaqqad: If there was an expression like $f(x) f(y)$ on one side of the equation, you would be right, but as stated there is not. So the Cauchy functional equation directly implies this functional equation, and the solution given shows that the reverse implication is also true, showing that these two functional equations are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $x=y=0$ we find $$f(0)=0.$$
Then with $y=-x$ we find $$f(x)=-f(-x)$$
for all $x\in\mathbb R$

Given $u,v\in\mathbb R$ with $u+v\ne -2$, let $x=\frac{u+v}2$ and $y=\frac{v-u}{u+v+2}$. Then 
$$ f(v)=f(xy+x+y)=f(xy)+f(x)+f(v)$$
and
$$ f(u)=f(-xy+x-y)=-f(xy)+f(x)-f(y)$$
so that 
$$ f(u)+f(v)=2f(\tfrac{u+v}2).$$
This also holds if $u+v=-2$, for then $-u-v\ne-2$ and $$f(u)+f(v)=-(f(-u)+f(-v))=-2f(-\tfrac{u+v}2)=2f(\tfrac{u+v}2).$$
As also
$$f(u+v)=f(u+v)+f(0)=2f(\tfrac{u+v}2)$$
we conclude
$$ f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v)$$
for all $u,v\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Elaqqad See the link in the comment on the question, title Cauchy functional equation for the solution to this functional equation.